# StructBlock within StreamField is rendered as text

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have an issue where I have a StrictBlock within a StreamField:

```
class DetailsTableBlock(StructBlock):
    title = CharBlock(required=False)
    description = RichTextBlock(required=False)
    table = TableBlock(template="home/blocks/table.html")

class MainStreamBlock(StreamBlock):
    ....
    table = DetailsTableBlock()
```

The problem occurs when I try to render the table using:

`{{ child.value.table }}`

all I get is:

`{u'data': [[u'test', u'test', u'test'], [u'123', u'asd', u'asd'], [u'123', u'asd', u'asd']], u'first_row_is_table_header': True, u'first_col_is_header': False}`

So the question is how can I render html using a StructBlock inside a StreamField? I am using Wagtail 1.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use: `{{ child.value.bound_blocks.table }}`

The full explanation is given at [wagtail documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/topics/streamfield.html#boundblocks-and-values), but in short: when you're looping over the content of a StreamField to output it, you'll sometimes get the raw data value, and sometimes get a `BoundBlock` object which knows both the value and how to render it as HTML. When you access the child values of a StructBlock, you get the raw values (since this is usually the more useful thing to access inside a StructBlock template) - to get the `BoundBlock` object, you need to read it from the StructBlock's `bound_blocks` dictionary instead.

Comment: Thanks once again for the detailed explanation. bound_blocks worked like a charm